# Pass variables set within a function to a method within a class

Tags: python

I'm quite confused as to how I can pass variables which are set within a function to a method, which is within a class.

Here is the code in question:

```
class monster():

    def __init__(self, health, name):
        print(name + " has been born!")
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.stats(name, health)

    def stats(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        print(self.name + "  -  " + str(self.health) + " HP")
```

I create an instance of `monster()` with this line at the start of the program:

```
gameMonster = monster(20, name)
```

However, you can see that the function `stats()` is supposed to display the **name** and **health** of the monster, which is set earlier. The game is in a **loop**, so the `stats()` function would be called after each "turn". However, I need to pass the variables `name` and `health` to `stats()` to be able to display them, but can't seem to figure out how.

My question is:

**How do I pass the variables, which are declared on initialisation of the method, to another method within the same class?**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *"I need to pass the variables `name` and `health` to `stats()`"* - **why?!** You've already set them in `__init__`, why not access them via `self.`? I strongly recommend you read a tutorial on Python classes/OOP.

Comment: This is extremely basic. Please read [the official tutorial on classes in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). TL;DR: You've set the variables as attributes `self.name` and `self.health` in your init method, meaning you can simply access them as `self.name` and `self.health` in all other methods of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set them again, they already live on the instance:

```
class Monster(object):    
    def __init__(self, health, name):
        print(name + " has been born!")
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.stats()

    def stats(self):
        print(self.name + "  -  " + str(self.health) + " HP")
```

And usage:

```
>>> monster = Monster(20, 'Boris')
Boris has been born!
Boris  -  20 HP

>>> monster.stats()
Boris  -  20 HP

>>> monster.health -= 5
>>> monster.stats()
Boris  -  15 HP
```